# Is there an OR-elimination rule for antecedent?

Tags: logic

I learned that

```
P, Q1 |- S,  
P, Q2 |- S
--------------------------
P, Q1 | Q2 |- S
```

Is the converse also true?

```
P, Q1 | Q2 |- S
--------------------------
P, Q1 |- S
```

and

```
P, Q1 | Q2 |- S
--------------------------
P, Q2 |- S
```

If not, is there a sufficient (introduction) and necessary (elimination) condition for `P, Q1 | Q2 |- S`?

Thanks.

Comment: Yes, if Q1 or Q2 implies S, then Q1 implies S, because Q1 implies Q1 or Q2.